# what is the relationsips between ubuntu, kubuntu and kernel

Tags: kernel

What is the relationship between Ubuntu, Kubuntu and kernel?

And do different distributions of Linux, such as Red Hat, openSUSE, use the same kernel?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29

Comment: This is an awesome graphic to help understand how these are related: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Linux_Distribution_Timeline.svg

Comment: @dan08 really awesome :D

Comment: I think this question is legitimate: the OP is just asking what is Linux and what are the differences between distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say Linux that actually means the Kernel, I think that's what you mean by "kenral"
so this kernel is being developed and a bunch of people or enterprises take it and build something upon it for example :

A community of people took the Linux kernel add some software and then created an Operating System called Debian. Then a company took that Debian and created something called Ubuntu.
Then.... you get the idea so this is why there are a lot of  Operating systems based on Linux, but since they all have this Linux software in common they  are called  "Linux Distributions".The Kernel is just a piece  software, make the bridge between Hardware and Software.

Ubuntu and Kubuntu are both "buntu" because they are based no just on the Linux Kernel but on Ubuntu either (Ubuntu it's based on Ubuntu... you get it) the difference is that Kubuntu uses a different environment called [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kde), from there the 'K', Ubuntu uses [gnome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) with unity on top of it.
There are a lot of Linux distros out there but there is a way they differ them.One way to distinguish them is by the type of packages they use some use ".rpm " some use ".deb"... or by dependency resolver, the software that makes sure that when you install a program you have all the little software needed for that greater software to work.

For example Ubuntu uses (.deb) and apt-get , Opensuse uses (.rpm) and zypper

Comment: Although all answers describe their relationships at a high level, this one gives me more details.

Answer (score 2):

- Ubuntu is a Linux distribution that branched from Debian.
- Kubuntu is a variant of Ubuntu with a different graphical environment (KDE)
- "The kernel is a computer program that manages input/output requests from software and translates them into data processing instructions for the central processing unit and other electronic components of a computer. The kernel is a fundamental part of a modern computer's operating system." (Wikipedia) — i.e. Windows also has a kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is an operating system. Just like Windows, mac OS X and so...

Kubuntu is an Ubuntu variant. It has a different "desktop environment" called "KDE". There are lots of other Ubuntu variants like "Lubuntu", for example, that uses "LXDE" desktop environment. The desktop environment is the part of the operating system that mainly controls how it looks and usually it would have various functions.

...About the kernel.

Ubuntu itself as a whole is based on "the Linux kernel". The kernel is the core part of the operating system. There are many operating systems out there based on the Linux kernel. Like "Debian", "Fedora" and yes; "openSUSE" and "Red Hat" too! They "are based" on the Linux kernel. Windows has its own kernel of course.